# Any chance of recovering/deciphering typewritten (monospaced) eroded text?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, ocr

I was looking for interesting problems to motivate me to implement my first NN classifier, and I think I found one; but perhaps I'm starting with something too difficult.

The problem is to get historical typewritten (monospaced) text and try to OCR them; only that they're badly eroded.

For example (after thresholding and line detection):
[image: Eroded text]

With some knowledge of the language and context, a human can solve this line (the font is not perfect, but I could invest more time in finding a better one if I find a promising approach):
[image: Recovered text]

There are worst cases also, that I couldn't decipher:
[image: Worst example]

#### First approach

My first approach was to try to have a sliding window over the text and XORing an image of every possible renderized character on the font I chose with the character in the window.
That didn´t work well because it bias detecting chars with fewer black pixels (such as "space"); the reason is that when there is a black pixel in the input, it's very likely part of a char - but when there is a white pixel, it could be part of an eroded char or not.

To fix that, I tried (experimenting with some values) to weight more black chars that match vs white chars; and many other things. They can somewhat detect some more obvious letters like the first "P" and "o", but there's also other biases that are hard to fix by trial and error.

### Tesseract

I also tried tesseract. It was better than my "counting black pixels", but still very far from deciphering even the less eroded line. I tried giving the whole sentence and also chars.

My feeling is that it's too generic to be used on monospaced text and I couldn't find any config to change that.

#### Generating eroded text for training - perhaps stable diffusion?

I also tried to create a set of eroded text; basically leaving just 10-15% of the black pixels from the letters; that looks kinda similar to the input I have, but it's not the same.. For instance, for some reason punctuations and some other parts of the text are less prone to be eroded - it's not random noise like I tried adding.

[image: A]
[image: A]
[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: B]
[image: B]
[image: a]
[image: a]
[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: b]
[image: b]

I didn't try to train a NN model on my generated input, but I'm not very confident it would work for the real input.

#### What else?

The only hope I have for solving this is some sort of NN that's trained not only on character recognition, but also the language (perhaps including words and usage frequency), but this is not looking like a pet project I can do in a few weekends.

Any ideas, starting points, literature?

Thanks!